Wilcoxon Signed Rank Test for a sample size of 4
My project has 4 pairs of values. Specifically, the concentration of a heavy metal in water before and after treatment. I've been told to make use of the Wilcoxon Signed Rank Test, but I've found that there are no critical values provided for a sample size of 4 with a small significance level. Are there any solutions to this? Are there any other tests I can make use of?
The main hypotheses we want to test out is if the treatment is effective in lowering the concentration level.

A number of answers to questions already on site address this.  With 4 pairs,  the smallest  attainable two sided significance level is 12.5%.

E.g. it's discussed here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/40626/805  and here https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/72029/805

Your best option at this point is a suitably chosen parametric model for concentrations. In future, however, its essential to figure out how you're going to test your hypotheses at the study design stage.

The advice about using some suitable parametric model when sample sizes are extremely small (in order that there's at least some chance of rejecting the null at your choice of significance level) can be found at the end of the answer here, for example: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/649922/805 . It would then be important to try to make the most of what data you have -- i.e. to make power a high as you can.

There's some related stuff in the comments here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/213598/alternative-to-wilcoxon-signed-rank-test-with-sample-size-6

Who and why did anyone "tell you" to use a Wilcoxon Sign Rank test (WSRt)? I will just refer you to @Glen_b's excellent comments; with 4 pairs, you can never get a result significant at the traditional $\alpha=.05$ significance level.
But also, the WSRt is a test of the pseudo-median (i.e. the median of all the possible paired averages of the paired differences). Why would that make your case?
The WSRt becomes a test of the median, iff the data (paired differences data) is symmetric. With only 4 observations, there is no way to ensure this is the case. And if it is the case, then the CLT will ensure convergence of the sampling distribution of the mean to a "normal-ish" distribution with very low sample sizes (even 4, in may cases, as is your case). So a paired t-test is your best bet at being able to find a significant difference.
And you may want to rethink who you get statistical advice from?
